# Enum creation using buildConfigField in build.gradle

Tags: java, android, enums, gradle

I've used Gradle for quite some time now but today I hit a snag. It seems one cannot create enums using the buildConfigField.

Ie. defining a String is as simple as:

buildConfigField "String", "APP_VERSION", "\"" + myVersionName + "\""

But trying the same with an emum results in some incorrect JAVA code.

```
buildConfigField "enum", "LanguageId", "{EN, DA, DE}"
```

results int

```
public static final enum LanguageId = {EN,DA,DE};
```

which should have been

```
public static final enum LanguageId {EN,DA,DE};
```

Is this a limitation or me doing something wrong ?

Added to the error list at the developers
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=101287

Comment: My guess is that it is a limitation. I do not really understand how you plan on using this, though. Your Java code in the `main` sourceset can only refer to enum values that exist in all build variants. So, if in build variant A, you define `LangaugeId` to be `{EN,DA,DE}`, and in build variant B, you define `LanguageId` to be `{EN, DE}`, then `main` can never refer to `LanguageId.DA`, as it will not exist when compiling build variant B.

Comment: It makes sense because I need the values for all builds and I want it defined here because I also need the data in gradle while building. Have a very fancy build script.

Comment: The devs have accepted this as a bug - so I'm hoping it will work some time in 2015 :)

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=101287